# Using two list to make rows and columns of matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to make a matrix with the rows and columns being passed as lists yvars and xvars. How would I make a matrix between the two and then populate it with the spearman correlation rho(using pspearman) between the column and the row title.

xvars and yvars are lists of names of the columns in the dataset access_sam2.

```
xvars <- c("Count_iTLS", "Count_iTLS_intra", "Count_iTLS_peri","Count_mTLS", "Count_mTLS_intra", "Count_mTLS_peri","Count_LA", "Count_LA_intra", "Count_LA_peri", "Distance_iTLS", "Distance_iTLS_intra", "Distance_iTLS_peri","Distance_mTLS", "Distance_mTLS_intra", "Distance_mTLS_peri","Distance_LA", "Distance_LA_intra", "Distance_LA_peri", "Area_iTLS", "Area_iTLS_intra", "Area_iTLS_peri","Area_mTLS", "Area_mTLS_intra", "Area_mTLS_peri","Area_LA", "Area_LA_intra", "Area_LA_peri")
yvars<-c("CD8_PD1_D","CD8_PDL1_D","CD8_GBNEG_FOXP3_D")
```

This is the code for the spearman correlation and to access the rho coeffecient

```
x<-spearman.test(access_sam2$x,access_sam2$y)
rho=x[["estimate"]][["rho"]]
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I have added the two lists xvars and yvars

Comment: You have two vectors with different length?  Is it a combination of correlation?

Comment: each of the the xvars and yvars are the name of a column in the same dataframe (they have the same number of rows(some are NA, but should be able to remove with na.rm=TRUE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
library(pspearman)
f1 <- function(x, y) spearman.test(access_sam2[[x]],
      access_same2[[y]])[["estimate"]][["rho"]]
outer(xvars, yvars, FUN = Vectorize(f1))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
f2 <- function(x, y) spearman.test(mtcars[[x]],
     mtcars[[y]])[["estimate"]][["rho"]]    

xvars <- c( "mpg",  "cyl",  "disp", "hp" )
yvars <- c("drat", "wt" )
out <- outer(xvars, yvars, FUN = Vectorize(f2))
out
#       [,1]       [,2]
#[1,]  0.6514555 -0.8864220
#[2,] -0.6788812  0.8577282
#[3,] -0.6835921  0.8977064
#[4,] -0.5201250  0.7746767

dimnames(out) <- list(xvars, yvars)
```

Comment: I got the error: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: @Andre As I mentioned, it is not tested.  You haven't provided any reproducible example

Comment: The data frame has 33 rows and 677 columns. All the vectors passed contain numbers.